# git stash apply directly into staging area

Tags: git

Is there a variant of `git stash apply` that adds the changes directly to the staging area rather than as untracked files?

According to the `git` man page, `pop` and `apply` both take the same arguments (`[--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]`) and neither is capable of applying a stash entry in such a way that the files touched are automatically included in the staging area as `git add` would do.

*Is there a workaround for automatically adding files touched by a stash entry to the staging area so that manually using `git add` after applying the patch is unnecessary?*

Here's a simple git repo that shows what happens when `git stash apply` is run, and a description of what I would like to have happen instead. Is there a git command that can apply a stash entry in this manner?

```
# boilerplate, create new environment for git repo
$ cd
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ mkdir bar
$ cd bar
$ git init

# create a new file with a single line
# consisting of 47
$ ed a.txt
a.txt: No such file or directory
0a
47
.
wq
3

# add file and create commit
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -m 'first'
[master (root-commit) 70a90c2] first
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
$ ed a.txt 
3
$a
204
.
wq
7

# show the status, note that a.txt is modified but tracked.
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   a.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
# add file to staging area
$ git add a.txt 
# save to stash
$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 70a90c2 first
HEAD is now at 70a90c2 first

# now we apply the topmost entry contained in the stash.
# however, upon applying this entry from the stash, the file
# a.txt is not "marked", requiring the user to manually go back
# and git add it.
$ git stash apply
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   a.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Your question is about git stash but it is not used  in your example

Comment: @simson `git stash save` and `git stash apply` are used near the bottom of the example. The example is intended to be complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a basic (but I think fixable) error in your question as asked:

> Is there a variant of git stash apply that adds the changes directly to the staging area rather than as untracked files?

The phrase *untracked file* has a specific meaning in Git, and `git stash` doesn't do anything with untracked files *unless* you use `git stash -a` or `git stash -u`, in which case it does kind of nasty and difficult things with them.  Fortunately you're just using `git stash save`, which doesn't do that.  I'll treat this as meaning "rather than to the work-tree".

To understand what's really going on, and why the ultimate answer to your question is both yes and no, you need to have a pretty clear picture of how Git keeps *three* copies of most files.  I say *most files* because *untracked* files, which I intend to ignore here, definitely do not have three copies.  If we ignore untracked files, and a few other corner cases that I will mention later, *all* files have this three-copies state.

#### Commits, the index, and the work-tree

Git's main unit of storage is the *commit*.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, some big ugly string such as `745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26`, that means that one particular commit and no other.  These hash IDs are, in effect, the true names of each commit.  Meanwhile each commit *stores* a frozen snapshot of all of your files.  These frozen snapshots are in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed form—sometimes very compressed—and because they're frozen for all time, they can be shared across different commits that have the same file *contents* for various files.

Each commit also stores some *metadata:* the name of the person who authored the commit, the name of the person who committed the commit into Git—usually these two are the same—and email addresses and time stamps and log messages and so on.  Each commit also lists the raw hash IDs of its immediate predecessor, or *parent* commit or commits.  It's the parent linkages that actually form the history in a Git repository.  As we're mostly concerned here with `git stash`, we don't need to look too much closer at this (but I'll mention it below).

Being frozen and unchangeable—not to mention inaccessible to most of your computer software—these freeze-dried snapshots of all of your files are great for archival, but completely useless for getting any actual *work* done.  Git therefore provides a way to extract an entire commit, using `git checkout` (or `git switch` since Git 2.23).  This, in effect, *copies* the committed files, expanding them out—defrosting and rehydrating them—into a work area.  Git calls this work area your *work-tree* or *work tree* or *working tree* or some other variant on this name.  It's pretty straightforward: that's where you can see and work with your files.

So that explains *two* of the three copies: there's the frozen one in the commit you have checked out right now, and the work-tree one.  If you have a `README.md` file, there's a frozen copy, and a useful copy.  Why is there a *third* copy at all?  That's a pretty good question, since other version control systems *don't* have a third copy.  But Git is Git, and Git insists on keeping a third copy.

This third copy lives in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The index copy is in the freeze-dried format, but unlike a committed copy, you can *replace* the index copy wholesale, at any time.  That's what `git add` does: it takes the work-tree copy, compresses it down into the freeze-dried format, and puts that in the index.<sup>1</sup>  This is also why—well, one of several reasons why—`git reset` exists and does what it does: it can copy the freeze-dried file from the current commit into the index, undoing the copying that you did with `git add`.

So, to review:

- One copy of the file is in `git show HEAD:README.md`.  That's the frozen, committed copy.  You can change which commit is `HEAD`, but if you use the raw hash ID instead of the name `HEAD`, you'll always get the same contents back.  This copy cannot be changed.
- One copy of the file is in `git show :README.md`.  That's the index, or staging area, copy.  You can replace it any time with `git add` to copy the work-tree copy into the index, or use `git reset` to copy the `HEAD` copy into the index.
- The last, and most useful to you, copy is in `README.md`: an ordinary file.  But Git doesn't really care about this one much: Git mostly cares about the frozen copy, and the index copy.

To make a *new* commit, Git simply packages up whatever is in the index / staging-area *right now*.  You run `git commit`, and Git freezes the ready-to-go files from the index into a new commit.  The new commit then becomes the `HEAD` commit and now the frozen and index copies match.  The work-tree doesn't even come into this picture at all—it's just left over from your initial `git checkout`.

You can think of the index as *what will go into your next commit*.  It just holds a (frozen-format) copy of every file, ready to commit.<sup>2</sup>

Note that running `git status` does *two separate comparisons:*  First it compares `HEAD` vs the index.  Whatever files are the same here, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git says *staged for commit*.  Then it compares the index to your work-tree.  Whatever files are the same here, Git says nothing.  For each file that is different, Git says *not staged for commit*.  There's no magic: you just get a message for files that are different.  They're in two separate groups because they're two separate comparisons.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, `git add` actually turns it into a *blob object* in the repository, and then stuffs the hash ID of the blob object into the index.  But it's OK to think of the file as being "in the index" until you get pretty deep into the internals of Git.

<sup>2</sup>The index takes on an expanded role during a *merge conflict*, but we'll ignore that here.

<sup>3</sup>Note: `git status --short` combines them into a more compact representation, but has to run both comparisons all the way through first.

---

#### Now we can understand `git stash`

What `git stash` does is pretty simple—or was, before all the fancy `git stash push -- <paths>` stuff went in, anyway.  Git makes new commits from the index.  You work with the work-tree.  So `git stash` makes *two* commits:

- One is just whatever is in the index right now, just like any ordinary commit.
- The second is made by copying all the tracked work-tree files *into* an index, then making a commit from that index.

I've slipped something sneaky in here: *an* index, rather than *the* index.  There is one distinguished, or *the*, index, but you can at any time make a temporary one, put whatever you want into it, and use that to make commits.  That's how `git stash` saves the work-tree copies of files.  Once it's made this commit, it removes the temporary index and you go back to having *the* index.

In any case, having made these two commits—which are special in that they're not on *any* branch—`git stash save` now runs `git reset --hard`.  So now all your tracked files match in *all three* copies, because `git reset --hard` takes the files from the frozen commit (which can't be changed), copies them into the index (overwriting any changed versions), and then from there, copies them into the work-tree (overwriting any changed versions).  That's OK, because the two commits that `git stash` just made have any changed versions that you *had* in the index and in your work-tree.

We can draw regular commits like this:

```
... <-o <-o <-o ... <-o   <--branch-name
```

The branch name holds the raw hash ID of the *last* commit in a chain of commits.  We say that the branch *points to* the commit.  The commit itself holds the raw hash ID of its immediate parent commit, so the commit points to its parent.  Its parent is a commit, which holds the hash ID of another parent.  So Git follows this chain backwards, one commit at a time, and that's the history in the repository.  **Branch names keep track of the last commit.**  Making a new commit adds more commits to the branch:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- develop
```

Here, the name `master` identifies commit `H`.  The name `develop` identifies commit `J`.  I use these letters to stand in for real hash IDs, which are way too long and random-looking to be useful to humans.  If we made a new commit on `master`, we'd add a commit `K` that points back to `H` and update the name `master` to point to `K`.

What about the `git stash` commits?  Well, to make them on *no* branch, here's what Git does:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
           |\
           i-w
```

Here, commit `i` is the one made with whatever was in the index before the `git reset --hard`.  Commit `w` is the one made with whatever was in a tracked file in the work-tree before the `git reset --hard`.  For whatever reasons,<sup>4</sup> commit `w` has the form of a merge commit—it has two parents, `i` and `H`—but it's not the result of running `git merge` and some Git commands will mis-display commit `w`, if you ask them to display it.

---

<sup>4</sup>Other arrangements could have been made, but making `w` a merge with two parents, or three parents for a `git stash -a` or `git stash -u` stash, was probably the most straightforward.  In any case that's how `git stash` actually does it.

---

#### Restoring a stash

No matter how you go about restoring a stash—with `git stash apply`, or with `git stash pop` which runs `git stash apply`, or even with `git stash branch` which also runs `git stash apply`—what Git does is:

- apply `i` to your index, or throw `i` away entirely; then
- use `git-merge-recursive` (the internal workhorse for a standard `git merge`) to merge commit `w` with your current work-tree, using the original parent of the stashed `w` and `i` commits—commit `H` in our example—as the merge base.

The end result of this is that there are some files in your index, and some files in your work-tree—which was also true before the apply, of course, but the first step might have changed the index copies, and the second step can change some work-tree copies.

Having applied these, `git stash pop` then invokes `git stash drop` if and only if both apply steps worked.  Either one can fail.  Note also that you can `git checkout` some commit that is *not* commit `H` before running `git stash apply`: having done this checkout changes what is in the index and in your work-tree.

Since `git status` just compares `HEAD`-vs-index and then index-vs-work-tree, any changes made by the *first* step are "staged for commit".  Any changes made by the *second* step are "not staged for commit".  Hence:

> Is there a variant of git stash apply that adds the changes directly to the staging area [...]?

1. No, because `git stash apply` depends on what's in `i`: no flags to `git stash apply` will make it run `git add` after running the recursive-merge step with commit `w`.
2. Yes, because `git stash apply` could apply what's in `i` to your index.

To make `git stash apply` use what's in commit `i`, you *must* use the `--index` option at the time you run `git stash apply`.  This means that if you invoke `git stash apply` via `git stash pop`, you must supply `--index` at that time.  If you forget, and the merge of stash-commit `w` goes well (or Git thinks so at least), Git will *drop* the stash and it becomes *very difficult* to *find* commit `i` again!  For this reason, among others, I recommend avoiding `git stash pop`.  In the bad old days, `git stash` didn't check option spelling very well, and `git stash --idnex pop` merrily destroyed your saved `i` commit and, ugh.

Of course, restoring the saved `i` commit doesn't always go well, and depends on you having run `git add` *before* you ran `git stash save`.  But it is useful.

(Note that `git stash branch` runs `git stash apply --index` for you, *after* first checking out the commit that the `i-w` stash-bag hangs from and creating a branch there.  So for this particular case, you don't need to add `--index`.)

#### Some corner cases

A stash can be made on some commit `H`, then you can `git checkout` some other commit entirely and run `git stash apply`.  In this case:

- the index / staging-area file contents you have now are probably at least somewhat different from those in the stash `i`
- the set of *tracked files* may be different: a file is tracked if and only if it is in the index *right now*

so here, when using `--index`, Git may not be able to apply your stashed `i` commit to your current index contents.  In that case, `git stash apply --index` will fail.  It will recommend that you try without `--index`.  This may not be good advice: if you had staged files on purpose, you probably should use `git stash branch` instead, at this point.

It's also possible to *remove* a file from the index after checking out some commit—so you can be on some commit, such as hash ID `H`, that has frozen files `README.md` and `README.TOO` and you can *remove* `README.TOO` from the index.  The *next* commit you make won't have a `README.TOO` file in it, but if `README.TOO` is in your work-tree—if you used `git rm --cached` for instance—the `README.TOO` file is now *untracked*.  Being untracked, `git stash save` won't save it in the `i` commit.  But it's in the `HEAD` commit, so `git stash save` *will* save it in the `w` commit (through some cleverness—basically the temporary index that `git stash save` uses to make `w` is based on `HEAD` rather than on the index).

These odd corner cases, when files exist in `HEAD` but not in the index, or in the index but not `HEAD`, make for tricky action with both regular `git commit` *and* with `git stash` commits.

If you *do* use `git stash save -a` or `git stash save -u`, Git will make a third commit to hold untracked files.  It will then *remove* the untracked files it put into this third commit.  Restoring this commit later requires that those files *not exist in the work-tree*.  If you've re-created them in any way, you will have to remove them—perhaps via `git stash save -u`—before you can apply or restore the earlier stash.

Side note: there is no difference between `git stash save` and `git stash push` in terms of *making* stashes.  The difference is that `git stash push` takes more options, and can therefore do a few extra things, such as partial stashes, that `git stash save` can't.  The `save` verb thinks all arguments are part of the log message to stick in the commits (in place of the default `WIP on ...`).

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff stash^..stash | git apply -3 --cached
```

The stash commit is the stashed worktree; its first parent is the stash base, `HEAD` aka  `@` at the time of the stash. So the diff is all the changes in the worktree as of the stash.  `git apply -3 --cached` says merge those changes to the index.